# <a href=""></a> not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

Code is W3C valid, and everything should be fine. But when user clicks the link nothing happens!

This link source is:

```
<a target="_blank" title="Download" href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shoutcast-radio/id299647180?mt=8">SHOUTcast Radio</a>
```

And you can see it in action:

1. visit http://afmrock.com/ ,
2. click upper right corner "Tune In" link
3. click/see link `SHOUTcast Radio` within the popup window, or other links within the window.

Comment: Are any of your scripts hijacking the `click` event?

Comment: afmrock.com uses this html: `<a onclick="javascript: navigation.set('tunein');   return false;" href="tune-in/">Tune in</a>` that's something totally different.

Comment: @binarious: Click on the links in the dialog box that appears.

Comment: Not sure it's related, but seeing a *ton* of these errors in Chrome:  `Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"`

Comment: In FF it appears to be making requests in a loop to other domains.

Comment: @KirkWoll that error is related to "shoutbox", I've disabled it, and problem was still there

Comment: copied the code directly into a test page and it worked fine for me.  Took me to http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shoutcast-radio/id299647180?mt=8  What else is on your page?

Comment: @Zanrok On page there are many links, but none of them in dialog box are working! Outside dialog box they work.

Comment: @enloz, I see the problem now.  It looks like you might have a conflict with whatever popup code you are using, fancybox whatever it might be.  I think it's trying to open a link within another popup.

Comment: the click event goes to div .inner .tunein - any click handlers on there?

Comment: @binarious I updated the OPs original question to better reflect the problem and how to reproduce it. Original question was misleading, I agree.

Comment: @Zanrok i'ts all custom code (except jQuery)

Comment: @enloz ya, I am guessing one of your custom scripts might be conflicting there then.  Sorry I can't track down which it is, but my original guess is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this file: /script/system.js

Remove the following:

```
$('.popup .inner').click(function () {
    return false;
});
```

This is disabling all click events inside that popup.

Answer (score 0):

Search your script files for something like ".preventDefault()"

It's gotta be something like that, because that syntax is absolutely correct.

@inkedmn's comment is the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

When I go to the links on the webpage it is downloading a pls file.  It is not the link you have posted.  The link you have posted works fine.  Right click on the link and inspect the element. You will see

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://stream.afmrock.com/listen.pls" title="Download listen.pls">http://stream.afmrock.com/</a>
```

The this will attempt to download the pls file.

If this is what was intended, then I am confused where you have the specified link at in your site.